# Left join no funciona correctamente

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Tengo la tabla clientes, que entre muchos campos tiene

`Id_sucursal, clave_cliente, razon_social`

Cuando quiero información de una sucursal, debo traer los datos de esta forma

`select * from clientes where id_sucursal='La sucursal que se ocupará'`

Ahora bien, tengo una tabla donde se almacenan las ventas, con un montón de campos

`Id_sucursal, Id_Consecutivo_Enca, cantidad_productos`

Ahora bien, cuando quiero saber cuántas compras ha realizado cada cliente, hago un join

```
select c.Id_sucursal, c.Razon_Social, ev.Cantidad_Prods from Clientes c inner join Enca_Ventas ev on c.Id_Sucursal=ev.Id_Sucursal and c.Clave_Cliente=ev.Id_Cliente
where c.id_sucursal='La sucursal que se ocupará'
```

Hasta ahí todo bien. Ahora me solicitaron un reporte donde se puedan ver los clientes con la cantidad de productos que han comprado, incluyendo aquellos que no han realizado compras con nosotros. Yo pensé: sencillo, en lugar de usar un `inner join` hago un `left join`, con eso debería traer todos los registros de la tabla clientes, y pondrá `null` en los clientes que no han comprado nada. Y zas! resulta que no funcionó :-(
Después de leer un poco, me enteré que el `where` podría ser el que me está ocasionando el problema. Así que pensé: Ok, movamos las condiciones al `on`, a ver qué pasa

```
select c.Id_sucursal, c.Clave_Cliente, c.Razon_Social, ev.Cantidad_Prods 
from Clientes c left join Enca_Ventas ev on c.Id_Sucursal=ev.Id_Sucursal and c.Clave_Cliente=ev.Id_Cliente and c.Id_Sucursal='La sucursal que se ocupará'
```

Pero tampoco funciona :-(
Ahora lo que trae son los registros de todas las sucursales con sus respectivas compras, de esta forma

```
Suc1    1   LIDIA ELENA PACHECO HERNANDEZ                                            NULL
Suc2    1   VICTOR HUGO SANDOVAL MORALES                                             NULL
Suc3    1   COLEGIO ATENEA ANIMAS S.C.                                               NULL
Suc4    1   ELIZABETH JUAREZ SILVESTRE / COPIAS GELY                                 NULL
Suc4    10  MARIA MARGARITA FLORES TRONCO / PAPELERIA DRAGON BALL / TRES VALLES      NULL
Suc3    10  CONTADORES Y ASESORES GUBERNAMENTALES DEL GOLFO S.C                      NULL
Suc2    10  AUTOMOTRIZ TEHUACAN S.A. DE C.V.                                         NULL
Suc1    10  MILTON JAVIER GONZALEZ LEON                                              NULL
```

¿Podrían orientarme qué estoy haciendo mal?
La idea es que sólo me trajera los datos de la sucursal que se puso en el `ON`

¡Gracias por su tiempo!

Comment: ¿? Según los resultados, tienes el mismo "clave cliente" para distintos clientes. ¿Estás seguro de que eso es un id? ¿No estarás haciendo el join con el campo equivocado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es el escenario que pareces indicar.

```
Create table clientes (Id_sucursal varchar(10), clave_cliente int, razon_social varchar(200));

create table Enca_Ventas(Id_sucursal varchar(10), Id_Consecutivo_Enca int, Cantidad_Prods int, id_cliente int)
go
Insert into clientes (Id_sucursal, clave_cliente, razon_social)
values
('Suc1',1,'LIDIA ELENA PACHECO HERNANDEZ'),
('Suc2',1,'VICTOR HUGO SANDOVAL MORALES'),
('Suc3',1,'COLEGIO ATENEA ANIMAS S.C.'),
('Suc4',1,'ELIZABETH JUAREZ SILVESTRE / COPIAS GELY'),
('Suc4',10,'MARIA MARGARITA FLORES TRONCO / PAPELERIA DRAGON BALL / TRES VALLES'),
('Suc3',10,'CONTADORES Y ASESORES GUBERNAMENTALES DEL GOLFO S.C'),
('Suc2',10,'AUTOMOTRIZ TEHUACAN S.A. DE C.V.'),
('Suc1',10,'MILTON JAVIER GONZALEZ LEON');
go
insert into Enca_Ventas (Id_sucursal, Id_Consecutivo_Enca, Cantidad_Prods, id_cliente)
values 
('Suc1',1,100,1),
('Suc2',1,100,1),
('Suc3',1,100,1);
go
```

En la tabla clientes, tienes una clave compuesta por id_sucursal y clave_cliente.

Si estás limitando los valores a la sucursal 'Suc1', y utilizas un left join, sólo tienes que poner la misma en el where.

```
select c.Id_sucursal
     , c.Clave_Cliente
     , c.Razon_Social
     , ev.Cantidad_Prods
       from Clientes AS c
                 left join Enca_Ventas AS ev on c.Id_Sucursal = ev.Id_Sucursal and c.Clave_Cliente = ev.Id_Cliente
       where c.Id_Sucursal = 'Suc1';
```

[image: Resultado]

Y tengo dos clientes asociados a Suc1 y de uno hay datos en Enca_Ventas, y por tanto la columna Cantidad_Prods tiene valor, y del otro no y por tanto es null.

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre hacerte la siguiente sugerencia; dato que tu tabla (digamos) *Universo* es **Clientes** el universo sería:

```
SELECT c.Id_sucursal, c.Clave_Cliente, c.Razon_Social
FROM Clientes c
```

Con lo anterior sin ninguna condición que excluya a ningún cliente *¡Ya tenemos a todos!*; ahora como requieres saber la cantidad de productos; implica (para mi, mayor facilidad) un subquery que te devuelva la cantidad de productos por cliente y sucursal como el que sigue (conforme lo que pusiste):

```
SELECT Id_Sucursal, Id_Cliente, SUM(cantidad_productos) cantidad_productos
FROM Enca_Ventas
GROUP BY Id_Sucursal, Id_Cliente
```

Ahora juntando todo:

```
SELECT c.Id_sucursal, c.Clave_Cliente, c.Razon_Social, cantidad_productos
FROM Clientes c
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT Id_Sucursal, Id_Cliente, SUM(cantidad_productos) cantidad_productos
   FROM Enca_Ventas
   GROUP BY Id_Sucursal, Id_Cliente
) ev ON c.Id_Sucursal=ev.Id_Sucursal and c.Clave_Cliente=ev.Id_Cliente
WHERE c.Id_Sucursal='La sucursal que se ocupará'
```

Lo anterior devolverá `null` en aquellos que no hay compra, ya conforme requieras le puedes poder el condicional que si es `null` ponga 0 (cero).

Comment: Gracias por tu apoyo!!!

Answer (score 0):

debes manejar ahi en GROUP BY masomenos de esta manera

select c.Id_sucursal, c.Clave_Cliente, c.Razon_Social, ev.Cantidad_Prods
from Clientes c left join Enca_Ventas ev on c.Id_Sucursal=ev.Id_Sucursal and c.Clave_Cliente=ev.Id_Cliente and c.Id_Sucursal='La sucursal que se ocupará' GROUP BY Id_Sucursal

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero con tu consulta no filtra la sucursal, trae todos los registros.